# SQL Server management studio viewing and altering a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, azure-sql-database, ssms

Just moved to sql azure from mysql / mysql workbench. I installed SQL Server Management Studio and was able to connect to the remote database on SQL Azure. Am able to view the database tables but how do I go about editing the tables or adding a column or a foreign key constraint. When I right click on the table it just gives me options for New Table, Script Table etc.

Does SQL Server Management Studio have something similar to the Mysql workbench UI. There were some posts discussing this but none specific to SQL Azure.

Comment: What version of Management Studio do you have installed? [Looks like R2 is required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621784.aspx#ssms)

Comment: Would management studio R2 express suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently any schema modifications can only be done via script.  The things you can do with the GUI are still pretty limited.  There are a number of 3rd party tools that offer varying degrees of functionality (houston, navicat, etc.) like you are expecting and I'm sure Microsoft's own offerings will improve.  But, for now... scripting is the bread and butter of managing Azure.

A lot of people keep a copy of the database locally to work on with the SSMS GUI. Then when they are happy with what they have use the GUI to create the scripts to apply to the AZURE copy.

Comment: Thanks...Moving over after using mysql workbench for quite a while. Not getting a good feeling about our move to Azure :)...

Comment: Edited my answer with another suggestion.